# How to add mask on UIImageView in Cell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, calayer

I've a tableView and I'm trying to add black mask on each image in the cell not on the whole cell just on the image. But I have two issues;

-It is masking the half cell from the left to the middle and each I scroll it is becoming darker. So please where would be my issue?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PlacesTableViewCell

        cell.backgroundImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: place.Image), placeholderImage: nil, options: .HighPriority)
}

class PlacesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    maskArrangement()
}

func maskArrangement(){
    var maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.frame.size.width, backgroundImage.frame.size.height)
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
    //backgroundImage.layer.mask = maskLayer
    backgroundImage.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you defining your PlacesTableViewCell? It is a custom cell type I gather? Do you have a custom class definition for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time cell is dequeued you are adding new sublayer to your backgroundImage. In this way it is getting darker when you scroll (when you dequeued your cells). I think you can add to your `PlacesTableViewCell` class at `awakeFromNib` method if it has a `.xib` file.

Meanwhile your image's frame should be half of the cell. Use autolayout to fix it's frame (for instance, set width and height constraints) in your PLacesTableViewCell class.

In @Shripada 's way:

```
class PlacesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var maskLayer : CALayer
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    maskArrangement()
}

    func maskArrangement(){
        if maskLayer == nil {
            maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.frame.size.width, backgroundImage.frame.size.height)
            maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
            //backgroundImage.layer.mask = maskLayer
            backgroundImage.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code. But your solution can be like that.

Comment: No it doesn't has a .XIB File. Could you please tell me the second way for that?

Comment: You can add a layer where you created your image in PlacesTableViewCell or you can add this layer in initWithCoder method in your PlacesTableViewCell

Comment: Or, have a member inside your cell, for the maskLayer. If the maskLayer exists already don't create one (when cell gets reused), if not, create if and set it as you are doing now.

Comment: It is working fine after I've added the layer in the 'PlacesTableViewCell' but still not in the correct place @CandostDagdeviren I have edited the code.